# Recursive Function that checks if a string is "Balanced"

Tags: c, string, algorithm, function, recursion

I have a question where I have to write an algorithm using recursion only (Must not use Loops).
The question says that my function should check if a given string is "Balanced" or not.
The string only contains letters (no symbols) and only ("**[**" , "**]**") those brackets. 
(For example: "**[aa][abbsa]**").

Assume that every "opening bracket" ("**[**") has a closing one ("**]**"), in other words, the brackets in the string are balanced and there's no need to check that.
The string is always one of these two formats:

1. **Simple String:** CHARACTERS.

it only contains characters with no brackets. (Example: "aaabbcc").

2. **String with 2 Sub-Strings:**

[***LEFT***][***RIGHT***]

***LEFT*** : Itself is a Sub-string that can actually be on of the two formats (Simple String OR String with 2 Sub-Strings)

***RIGHT*** : Itself is a Sub-string that can actually be on of the two formats (Simple String OR String with 2 Sub-Strings)

***EDIT:*** The string is Valid, there's no need to check if it's legal or not.
it's always one of the mentioned formats and examples (might be more complicated too, but it's always legal).

***EDIT:*** The String can only be in the 1st format, or the 2nd format. if it's the 2nd format, then it includes the 1st format, and it must start with "[" and end with "]".
Examples: "aaabbbb" (1st format). "[aa][bbbb]" (2nd format). "[[aa][b]][[[a][bbb]][aaaa]]" (2nd format).

The string is Balanced if it fulfills at least one of the following conditions:

1. The string is from the 1st Format.
2. The string is from the 2nd Format and also the number of the characters (without the brackets) in the LEFT side (lets call it weight) is EVEN, and so is the weight in the RIGHT side.
3. The string is from the 2nd Format and also the weight in the LEFT side is ODD and so is the weight in the Right side.

Examples:

The string "**[abcde][xyz]**" is Balanced, because the Right weight and the Left weight are both ODD.

The string "**[abcde][xyzw]**" Isn't Balanced, because the Right Weight is EVEN (4 is even) and the Left Weight is ODD (5 is odd).

The string "**[abcdef][[x][yzw]]**" is Balanced.
The Left weight is 6.
The Sub-String "**[x][yzw]**" is Balanced. (Left weight is 1, Right weight is 3 (Both ODD)).
The weight of "**[x][yzw]**" is 4.
Therefore, "**[abcdef][[x][yzw]]**" is Balanced, since both of the Left and Right weight are EVEN.

"**[[abcde][xyzw]][Z]**" is Balanced, even though the Sub-String "**[abcde][xyzw]**" isn't Balanced! because its weight is 9, and "**[Z]**" weighs 1, They're both ODD.

So, I have to write a recursive function in C, that receives a "string".

```
int verify_weight(char s[])
{
    //Code I need here
}
```

it checks the string and the Sub-strings in it and then prints each one if them if its balanced or not.
for example:
string "**[[aa][b]][[[x][yy]][hhhhh]]**".
it prints this: 
imbalanced: 2,1
imbalanced: 1,2 
balanced: 3,5
imbalanced: 3,8

I'm also allowed to create another functions to help with solving it (recursive only).

***EDIT: (ANSWER)*** 
Thank you guys for the nice solutions, This is @kolmar's solution.

Code: (edited after @kolmar's Answer for function names of mine)

```
#include "stdio.h"

int between_balanced(char s[], int n)
{
  if (!s[0] || (s[0] == ']' && n == 1)) return 0;
  return 1 + between_balanced(s+1, n + (
    s[0] == '[' ? 1 :
    s[0] == ']' ? -1 :
    0
  ));
}

int verify_weight(char s[])
{
  if (s[0] == '[') {
    int left = verify_weight(s+1);
    int right = verify_weight(s + between_balanced(s, 0) + 2);

    if (left % 2 == right % 2) {
      printf("balanced: ");
    } else {
      printf("imbalanced: ");
    }
    printf("%d,%d\n", left, right);

    return left+right;
  } else {
    return between_balanced(s, 1);
  }
}
int main() {
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s", s);
        printf("%d\n", verify_weight(s));
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for this long question, but I really need help with it, I spent a lot of time trying to solve it but i couldn't. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: It's for my sister, she has an exam in recursion and she has been studying for days. she asked me about this question and I couldn't solve it, we spent a lot of time trying to solve it but we couldn't.. i think we're missing some basic things in recursion.

Comment: Have you tried to write anything at all?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried, I'm not that good at C, but I tried also in C#. it didn't work out for me, I couldn't find a way how to get to the right side and check if it's as the same as the left side (odd or even)..

Comment: The basic function should find the left and right halves of the string, then recursively call itself to get the weights of the two halves. It can then print out if they are balanced or not, and return the total weight by summing the returns of the two recursive calls. You'll have to work out how to handle the base cases such as empty strings or strings with no substrings. We can't really do much more for you until you implement some actual code and come back with the specific problems you're having.

Comment: also inside recursion  i guess one will have to use loops , what do you actually mean by "NO LOOPS": not an iterative solution or no loops at all ?

Comment: @sasha that's what i was thinking about.

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned not being able to find a way to get the right side. A useful trick when dealing with paired parenthesis or brackets is to keep a running count. Each time you see an open bracket increment it, and decrement each time you see a close bracket. When the counter hits zero it means you just read the closing bracket at the end of the left string, so the next character must be the beginning of the right string.

Comment: @sasha, No loops at all. and [][ab] is not valid, since "[]" doesn't contain any characters, don't mind the "string validation" assume that its always legal

Comment: @katie, i tried to run a counter by doing cnt++ and cnt-- each time i find a bracket, but then i had a problem and i couldn't deal with it, its with the sub-string by checking if they're balanced or not and printing the weights of them. (for example: "[[aa][b]][aaa]" I couldnt check [aa][b].. and so on

Comment: @BukLau, that check should be handled by a recursive call.

Comment: @BukLau is that your real name or do you watch OwnagePranks on Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

Purely recursive version (using auxiliary functions).

The idea is to find where the left side ends (using `left_side`), then count the number of non-bracket chars in each side (using `count_side`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int left_side(char* s, int i, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0) return i;
    if (s[i] == '[') return left_side(s, i+1, depth+1);
    if (s[i] == ']') return left_side(s, i+1, depth-1);
    return left_side(s, i+1, depth);
}

int count_side(char* s, int a, int b) {
    if (a==b) return 0;
    return count_side(s, a+1, b) + (s[a] != '[' && s[a] != ']');
}

int is_balanced(char* s) {
    if (s[0] != '[') return 1;
    int size = strlen(s);
    int left = left_side(s, 1, 1);
    return count_side(s, 0, left)%2 == count_side(s, left, size)%2;
}

int main() {
    char s[256];
    while(scanf("%s", s) != EOF) {
        printf("%s\n", is_balanced(s) ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask to verify if the input is following the specification. Only if given the specification it is balanced. And "ab[c]" isn't a valid input string. C.f. "The string is always one of these two formats".

Comment: @BukLau can you verify whether string is always valid or not ?

Comment: I explained it wrong, it can only be the 1st format, or the 2nd format. if it's the 2nd format, then it includes the 1st format, and it must start with "[" and end with "]". sorry about that.. I edited it in the question too.

Comment: to be strictly correct, you need a recursive definition of `strlen` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Single function solution:

```
// rs - if we are in the right side bracket now
// ob - unmatched open brackets in the left hand side
// wl - weight of left side
// wr - weight of right side
// call as check(your_string, 0, 0, 0, 0)
int check(char *s, int rs, int ob, int wl, int wr) 
{
  if (!*s) return !rs || wl % 2 == wr % 2;
  if (rs) return check(s+1, rs, ob, wl, wr+1);
  if (s[0] == ']') return check(s+1, ob==1, ob-1, wl, wr);
  if (s[0] == '[') return check(s+1, rs, ob+1, wl, wr);
  return check(s+1, rs, ob, wl+1, wr);
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the solution, that prints for each substring in Format 2, whether it is balanced or imbalanced:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int get_length(char *s, int open_brackets)
{
  if (!*s || (s[0] == ']' && open_brackets == 1)) return 0;
  return 1 + get_length(s+1, open_brackets + (
    s[0] == '[' ? 1 :
    s[0] == ']' ? -1 :
    0
  ));
}

int get_weight(char *s)
{
  if (s[0] == '[') {
    int left = get_weight(s+1);
    int right = get_weight(s + get_length(s, 0) + 2);

    if (left % 2 == right % 2) {
      printf("balanced: ");
    } else {
      printf("imbalanced: ");
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", left, right);

    return left+right;
  } else {
    return get_length(s, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Only one thing, isn't "abc" supposed to be valid?

Comment: `[0][[00][0]]` has an unbalanced right side in [[00][0]] but this returns true.

Comment: @rpattiso Having a unbalanced side doesn't make the whole string unbalanced. C.f. ""[[abcde][xyzw]][Z]" is Balanced, even though..." (and `[[00][0]]` isn't valid input, only `[00][0]` is).

Comment: @JuanLopes Yeah, forgot about that case, fixed now.

Comment: @JuanLopes how do you accomplish "it checks the string and the Sub-strings in it and then prints each one if them if its balanced or not."

Comment: @kolmar, thank you for this solution, I have edited the main question with the answer (yours) and the problem that i have with it. The function doesn't seem to stop, I think it runs to infinite and gets stuck.. how can I fix it? Thank you! :)

Comment: @BukLau `printf("%s\n", verify_weight(s));` I think this is the problem. `verify_weight` returns `int`, but you are trying to print it with `%s`. It should just be called it as a statement `verify_weight(s);`, it prints everything internally.

Comment: @kolmar, yes it actually is, thank you! it works really fine, thank you for this nice solution :).

Comment: @BukLau Glad, it helped. Also, your edit `if (!s` instead of `if (!*s` in `between_balanced` is wrong. `s` is still a pointer, even if you send it in as `char s[]`. The reason for this `!*s` check is to stop recursion, when the user input is in Format 1. If input is guaranteed to always be in Format 2 you can remove the `!s ||` part altogether. If input can be in Format 1, it should be here as `!*s` or `!s[0]`, but not `!s`

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget about the fact that we cannot use loops for a while and try to think about an algorithm that solves it. What we need to do is to find a position of the matching closing bracket for each opening bracket in the given string. After that the solution becomes almost trivial: we can create a helper function that takes a an array of char and two indices: lower and upper bound and does the following(it is a pseudo code):

```
// low is inclusive, high is not.
int get_weight(char[] s, int low, int high) {
    if (low == high || s[low] is not a bracket) // The base case: a simple string.
        return high - low;
    int mid = get_matching_index(low); // An index of a matching bracket.
    // Solves this problem recursively for the left and the right substrings.
    int left_weight = get_weight(s, low + 1, mid);
    int right_weight = get_weight(s, mid + 2, high - 1);
    // Prints balanced/imbalanced depending on the left_weight and the right_weight.
    return left_weight + right_weight;
}
```

So the question is how to find matching pairs of brackets. If we could use loops, we could apply a standard stack-based algorithm(iterate over the string from left to right and push a position to the stack if it is an opening bracket and pop the top element from the stack if it is a closing one). Even though we are not allowed to use a loop, we can emulate it:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // do something 
}
```

can be implemented as

```
void iterate_recursively(int i, int n) {
    if (i < n) {
        // do something
        iterate_recursively(i + 1, n);
    }
}

...

iterate_recursively(0, n)
```

An implementation of a stack does not require any loops, so that's it.

Comment: There must be a way to solve it using recursion only, and without using stacks (this question is for my sister, and they haven't learned stacks and queues yet)

Comment: I don't know what the specifics of the question are but generally when someone says write a recursive solution , it does not mean that you can't use loops it just means a recursive solution not iterative . And in case you don't want loops then ILoveCoding has suggested the method.

Comment: I understand, but the question demands recursion only. it's for my sister's test, and it's only using recursion.

Comment: then ILoveCoding's method is what you want

Comment: @BukLau Well, a stack size is limit by the string length so it can implemented with just an array.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on matching the accumulated score (weight) with target_score. Scoring function is very simplified version of hash function. Since "Balanced" is 8 byte long, the value should be able to sit in 64bit long integer.

Wrote in python but it in a way similar to C.

```
def wfunc(s):
    ret = 0
    for x in s:
        ret <<= 8
        ret |= ord(x)
    return ret

def find_balanced(buf, index, score, target_score):
    end = len(buf) == index
    score_hit = score == target_score
    if end:
        return score_hit
    c = buf[index]
    enclosed = c == '[' or c == ']'
    if enclosed:
        if score_hit:
            return True
        else:
            # Reset accumulated value
            return find_balanced(buf, index+1, 0, target_score)
    score <<= 8
    score |= ord(c)
    return find_balanced(buf, index+1, score, target_score)


find_balanced('[Orama][Koma][[exmp][Balanced]', 0, 0, wfunc('Balanced')) # True
find_balanced('[Orama][Koma][[exmp][Balanceded]', 0, 0, wfunc('Balanced')) # False
find_balanced('[Orama][Koma][[exmp][Balance]', 0, 0, wfunc('Balanced')) # False
```